# Sent to contract address

Tags: 0x

Hi I made a mistake by sending my WETH to the WETH contract address is there a way to recover my funds? I'll send proof of the transaction.[image]

0x88f8ef43fac9819d49172af7a070afd95b6cab8bfd5dbd969052aafcfd453e7a

Comment: Would be helpful to see more information, like a transaction hash, or at least the address of receiving WETH contract.

Comment: Hi I added the transaction hash

Comment: OK... this is Polygon WETH, meaning it's not wrapping the native token, but rather just a normal ERC20 token. I don't see any rescue function, but you can try to contact someone at https://weth.io/ (no idea if that's even possible) and see if they can help you.

Comment: Yeah, I dont even know where to find their socials

Answer (score 1):

The [standard implementation](https://github.com/gnosis/canonical-weth/blob/master/contracts/WETH9.sol) of WETH doesn't have any rescue functions, so it's probably lost.

Go to the address of the WETH token you sent to, try to check the source code since there are multiple implementations of this contract, also try to contact the owners of the contract.

But chances are very slim.

Answer (score 0):

I think that these funds are lost as the smart-contract does not have any function that could allow the owner of the contract to send your funds back to your wallet.

https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#readContract

But try to reach the owner(s), just in case they would have the private key associated to the smart-contract address (but I don't believe so).

Comment: I sent WETH to its own contract address. Who is the owner of WETH contract address?

Comment: I don't know. I know their website is https://weth.io/
But anyway I think they won't have the private key of the smart-contract address wallet. When one deploy a smart-contract to the Ethereum blockchain, no private key is needed because private keys are only needed for pure wallets. It's very rare to have the private key associated to a smart contract address "wallet".